# Carrierwave AWS Heroku : current_path and File.read can't find the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

I have (what I thought was) a perfectly working Heroku-Carrierwave-AWS.

I can upload images like a charm.

I now need to send the respective images, via a JSON request, to an app. This has been working on my test server, but for some reason I'm getting the following from my Heroku Logs from my rails call:

```
Started POST "/downloadUserPhotos" for ?? at 2014-05-03 03:27:38 +0000
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - uploads/photo/mainphoto/1/largeimage.jpg):
app/controllers/stats_controller.rb:22:in `read'
app/controllers/stats_controller.rb:22:in `downloadPhotos'
```

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the following Ruby/Rails code:

```
def downloadPhotos
  @photos = Photo.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  @mainphoto = Base64.strict_encode64(File.read(@photos.mainphoto.current_path))
end
```

When I use my console on Heroku and type the following:

```
@photos = Photo.find(1)
```

It works and I get the correct record shown. When I ask for current_path for mainphoto, I get:

```
irb(main):002:0> @photos.mainphoto.current_path
=> "uploads/photo/mainphoto/1/largeimage.jpg"
```

So, it knows it exists. And it's in the right place.

Can anyone enlighten me (or point me in the right direction) as to why I can't use File.read. And, more importantly, how I get it to now read the image file and encode it??

This has perplexed me somewhat.

I've tried to use @photos.mainphoto.url, but other than giving me the whole URL, it still doesn't find the file using File.read.

My carrier wave config is:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {

    # Configuration for Amazon S3
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
  }

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"

  config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']

end
```

And I have the following in my Uploader:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.user.id}"
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
@mainphoto = Base64.strict_encode64(File.read(@photos.mainphoto.current_path))
```

Change `current_path` for `url`